# Ubuntu Mate on Yoga 300 not booting, no bios screen, nada

Tags: boot, bios

I did a clean install of **Ubuntu Mate 16.04** on my new Lenovo Yoga 300.Installation went fine, so I **upgraded to 17.10 immediately**, rebooted a couple of times, installed some software from the "boutique", tested a couple of things, then shut it down. The next time I tried switching it on, the power button and it just flashes. Neither the Bios options or the Boot menu show up. Just a flashing button. 
I tried taking off the back to check for loose connectors and to disconnect the battery to make a clean start, everything was intact and the battery is soldered in, so won't be disconnected. 
I seem not to find the cause of this problem and I see no way of fixing it, so it will have to be returned unless there is a magic solution/explanation.

Any ideas?

Comment: **(1)** It would be much better to install 17.10 directly instead of using the detour through 16.04. Release upgrades *usually* work but they *may* introduce issues or leave useless clutter behind. A direct installation is far cleaner and avoids potential issues. **(2)** If your computer doesn't show anything on the display at all, not even a BIOS post screen or an error message, the issue is most likely unrelated to Ubuntu. I requested a migration to [SU].

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with Lenovo devices, it's stuck in sleep or hibernation mode. It's unrelated to Ubuntu.

Try holding the power button down for a while first, but if that doesn't work tour Yoga should have an Emergency Reset 'hole' and putting a paperclip into it to depress the little button inside should turn it off, according to Lenovo community support:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-S-Series-ThinkPad-Yoga/thinkpad-yoga-is-not-response-to-power-button-in-sleep-mode/td-p/1415213

Comment: I've tried all combinations of holding button down, inserting paperclip, etc. but make no difference. the power button flashes slowly and when pressed,  there is sometimes a brief, faint sound something like a HDD starting, but it dies within half a second or less.

Comment: Sounds fatal mate, is it under warranty?

Comment: Luckily, yes. Seems like an odd coincidence, though. Hard to imagine that it would die overnight while switched off and not being charged. Now worried about doing the same thing to its replacement...

Comment: This is a huge problem with Lenovo - I did some googling and there are lots of examples across a range of devices.

Comment: Yoga was returned with new motherboard and now works perfectly with 17.04 Budgie. They may have upgraded the BIOS - speculating that they knew abut this or similar issue. Not an Ubuntu problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yoga 3 returned with Windows 10 loaded (!) and working again. So I installed Ubuntu Budgie over it... and it kind of worked, but it was slow and cranky and about 1 in 3 boots would fail with a white screen, so I installed Peppermint OS an it has been really fast and responsive ever since. So Peppermint is my recommended distro for the Lenovo Yoga 3.